# how do i get even placed digits from a number in java

Tags: java

I want my program to get all the even digits from a number input. Then multiply those with digits with 2. If the result is a two digit number, add them. At the end i want it to give me the sum of all the even digits.
public class evenplaceadd {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println(sumOfevenPlace(5566));
}
public static int sumOfevenPlace(int number)
{
    int maxDigitLength = 4;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxDigitLength; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            int digita = number % 10;
            int digitb =digita*2;
            int digitc;

            if(digita < 9)
            {
                sum = sum + digitb;
            }
            else if(digitb>9)
            { 
                digitc =(digitb % 10)+ (digitb /10);
                sum =sum + digitc;  
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            number =  number/10;
        }

    }
    return sum;
```

}

}

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet?  Could you at least make us feel like we're not doing your homework?

Comment: Such a troll question as well, what you're requesting doesn't make sense grammatically.

Comment: Please provide what ever code you have so far, and we can help you figure it out from there. We do not like giving answers to homework. It seems like this is a intro to java class homework assignment lol.

Comment: I updated my question .Using this code i am getting 24 as my answer.

Comment: @randeepsingh check the code i provided as an answer and see if it is the expected output. I get 12 as the output with the code. Your question was not clear enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok for the most part. There are some minor flaws in the code which I am sure you will be able to figure out after understanding the code provided below. I have changed it up a bit and made it easier to read. Please confirm it is working, and next time please provide the code when asking question. I know you are new to the community, and so am I. Its a learning experience for all of us. All the best in the future :)

```
public static void int sumOfEvenDigits(int num){
    int sum = 0;
    int lastDig = 0;
    while(num/10 != 0)
    {

        lastDig = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        if(lastDig % 2 != 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(lastDig > 10)
        {
            sum += lastDig / 10;
            sum += lastDig % 10;
        }
        else
        {
            sum += lastDig;
        }

    }
    return sum;
}
```